# Как добавить в сайдбар гутенберга панель

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, gutenberg

Не могу разобраться как добавить дополнительную панель в правую часть gutenberg редактора на всех страницах и постах. **Добавить нужно НЕ метабокс, а именно панель.**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В документации нашел код - https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/components/panel/ , но он не работает либо код не полностью написан.

```
import { Panel, PanelBody, PanelRow } from '@wordpress/components';
import { more } from '@wordpress/icons';

const MyPanel = () => (
    <Panel header="My Panel">
        <PanelBody title="My Block Settings" icon={ more } initialOpen={ true }>
            <PanelRow>My Panel Inputs and Labels</PanelRow>
        </PanelBody>
    </Panel>
);
```

Кроме этого код не подключается в php, т.к требует подключение wp-polyfill в dependencies в строке

```
wp_register_script( 't-script', $this->plugin_url() . '/build/index.js', array('wp-components', 'wp-data', 'wp-edit-post', 'wp-element', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-plugins', 'wp-polyfill'), null);
    wp_enqueue_script( 't-script');
```

но если я его указываю то скрипт не подключается. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Вот работающий пример плагина с панелью.
В репозитарии также есть примеры других блоков с настройкой в панели
[repo плагина с панелью](https://github.com/Ulibka68/gutenberg-course-blocks/blob/__final_VLA_project/src/plugins/sidebar.js)

P.S. смотрите только ветку __final_VLA_project